# How to get exact string format of float value

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a float value, let say:

```
value = 0.12345
```

And I have a list of other floats :

```
values = [1.04, 2.045, 2.0]
```

I would like to get exact format of the value smth like:

```
# result should be'0.5f'
format_str = Formatter.get_float_format(value)

# and apply that format to values in the list
values = [1.04, 2.045, 2.0]
for v in values:
  print({format_str}.format(v))
```

How to do this?
I only found a lot of answers of a second part of my question, but cant find a solution of gettting a specific float format...

Comment: Check [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting it right, so you want every float in your list to become a string with the following format `0.5f` ? if so  the following snippet will do the magic `formated = [str(float)[:3]+'f' for float in values]`

Comment: You can define the decimal `5` in `0.5f` easily. Check if my answer makes sense to you!

Answer (score 2):

```
def format_floats(reference, values):
    formatted_values = []
    for i in range(len(values)):
        length = len(str(reference)[str(reference).find("."):])-1
        new_float = str(round(values[i], length))
        new_float += "0"*(len(str(reference))-len(new_float))
        formatted_values.append(new_float)

    return formatted_values

if __name__ == '__main__':

    reference = 0.12345
    values = [1.04, 2.045, 2.0]

    print(format_floats(reference, values))
```

output: ['1.04000', '2.04500', '2.00000']

Answer (score 1):

```
value = 0.12345
values = [1.04, 2.045, 2.0]

value_length = len(str(value).split('.')[-1]) # length of numbers after a coma -> 5
float_format = '{0:.' + str(value_length) + 'f}' # -> {0:.5f}

for v in values:
    print(float_format.format(v))
```

**Output:**

```
1.04000
2.04500
2.00000
```

Answer (score 1):

I counted the number of digits after the decimal point, and created the format string according to the length.

So the format string of `2.045` will be `0.3f`, and `0.1f` for `2.0` etc.

```
def get_format(value):

    #dec is the number after decimal point
    dec = str(value).split('.')[1]
    #Created the format string using the number of digits in dec
    format_str = '0.{}f'.format(len(dec))
    print(format_str)
    print(format(value, format_str))

values = [ 0.12345, 1.04, 2.045, 2.0]

for value in values:
    get_format(value)
```

the output looks like

```
0.5f
0.12345
0.2f
1.04
0.3f
2.045
0.1f
2.0
```